# Mysql query for highest vote perday

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a following db table `review_vote`

```
review_id | user_id | status | date_added 
 2             3        good     20130116135259
 3             3        normal   20130116145259
 4             2        normal   20130116155259
 5             2        good     20130116165259
 6             2        good     20130116175259
 7             1        great    20130116185259
 8             3        good     20130117135259
 9             3        normal   20130117145259
```

currently I can get the highest vote by using the following query:

```
SELECT review_id FROM review_vote GROUP BY review_id HAVING COUNT(*) = 
(
   SELECT MAX(x.counts) FROM 
   ( 
       SELECT review_id, COUNT(*) counts FROM review_vote GROUP BY review_id
   )x 
) 
order by date_added desc
```

but if i need to get highest vote perday how can i modified the code above? Which means if today were `2013-01-16` I need to get highest vote for yesterday `2013-01-15`

my attempt to use `date_added = CURDATE()` is failed. 
SQLFIDDLE: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9a2b5/6

Update query:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `review_vote` (
  `review_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `date_added` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  KEY `review_id` (`review_id`,`user_id`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;



INSERT INTO `review_vote` (`review_id`, `user_id`, `status`, `date_added`) VALUES
(223, 2, 'lame', '20130116195259');
INSERT INTO `review_vote` (`review_id`, `user_id`, `status`, `date_added`) VALUES(222, 2, 'lame', '20130115195259');
```

Comment: if you need per day then you also need to group by the day

Answer (score 1):

Just add this in your where condition:

```
DATE_FORMAT(date_added, '%Y-%m-%d') = CURDATE()
```

Updating as per your error

```
SELECT review_id FROM review_vote AS RV WHERE DATE_FORMAT(RV.date_added, '%Y-%m-%d') = CURDATE()    
    GROUP BY review_id HAVING COUNT() = 
(
    SELECT MAX(x.counts) FROM 
    (
        SELECT review_id, COUNT() counts FROM review_vote GROUP BY review_id
    )x
)
```

Please have a look at demo :[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9a2b5/16)

Comment: error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE `date_added` DATE_FORMAT(date_added, '%Y-%m-%d') = CURDATE()' at line 10: SELECT review_id FROM review_vote GROUP BY review_id HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT MAX(x.counts) FROM ( SELECT review_id, COUNT(*) counts FROM review_vote GROUP BY review_id) x ) WHERE `date_added` DATE_FORMAT(date_added, '%Y-%m-%d') = CURDATE()

Comment: @SaraswathiApavoo: your query is wrong just update as per my post.

Comment: are you sure it works..? i just copy you code in sqlfiddle it still shows error

Comment: WHERE clause should be before GROUP BY

Comment: @SureshKamrushi look at create table query that i update, the above query doest not works well

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT   review_id
FROM     review_vote
WHERE    date_added LIKE '20130115%'
GROUP BY review_id
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT    1
```

But really you ought to consider changing your `date_added` column to an appropriate temporal type, like [`DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/datetime.html).

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your WHERE clause:

```
`date_added` BETWEEN
  DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY), '%Y%m%d')
  AND DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y%m%d')
```

Make sure you have an index on `date_added`!

Documentation for the date functions is all here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Life would be easier for you if your `date_added` column was a native date type.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE `date_added` BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY), '%Y' at line 10: SELECT review_id FROM review_vote GROUP BY review_id HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT MAX(x.counts) FROM ( SELECT review_id, COUNT(*) counts FROM review_vote GROUP BY review_id) x ) WHERE `date_added` BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY), '%Y%m%d') AND DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y%m%d')

Comment: Your `WHERE` is in the wrong place, it should go after the `FROM`.